# When does a morphism of bounded complexes induce distinguished triangles in the bounded derived category?

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

I have a very basic question about the triangulated structure of bounded derived category of finitely generated modules.

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring, and $\text{mod } R$ be the abelian category of finitely generated modules. Let $M^{\bullet}$ and $N^{\bullet}$ be bounded cochain complexes of finitely generated modules and $f:M^{\bullet} \to N^{\bullet}$ be a morphism of complexes that induce injective maps on cohomologies.
Then, does this induce a distinguished triangle $M^{\bullet} \to N^{\bullet}\to L\to $ in the bounded derived category $\text{D}^b(\text{mod } R)$ ?